# bootstrap-ui tab select and error "cannot read property $$phase of null"

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-grid

There is this known issue with ng-grid: if the grid has width 100% and it is hidden (eg: inside a bootstrap-ui tab) and then unhidden (eg. the tab is shown), then the grid is kind of messed up.

I'm currently solving this by triggering a $(window).resize() event, like this:

**view_with_tabs:**

```
<tabset>
    <tab>...</tab>
    <tab>...</tab>

    <tab select="ngGridFix()">
        <tab-heading>
            <strong>My grid</strong>
        </tab-heading>

        <div id="my-grid" ng-grid="myGrid" style="width: 100%; height: 180px"></div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

**controller:**

```
$scope.ngGridFix = function() {
    $(window).resize();
};
```

This works super fine except for one harmless error:
When I navigate from that view to another view controlled by another controller, say:

```
 /#/view_with_tabs---> /#/other_view
```

I get this javascript error, seen in the developer console:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$phase' of null
```

It is thrown 8 times or more:

[image: phase of null]

As I said, this error is harmless.. I'm not losing any functionality, but I want to get rid of it.

I guess that when I click on the link that goes from one view to the other, the tab triggers all the `select`, and all of my tab have one (there are 7 tabs with this `select="ngGridFix()"`)

How can I solve this? any alternative to fixing this ng-grid problem?
I'm using ng-grid 2.0.13